# p5.js replace let url to local link

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Im noob with p5j and i need help from someone please! :-(

On the website i must upload it , they not allow the external links.
and i need to change the "let url" to a png/jpg local link ( not external link ).

i dont know what the solution is ( maybe something similar with: "loadImage" or something.... please help me :-) )

Thank you so much and have a blessed week!

Here is the code:

```js
//let url = "https://coolors.co/3a2e39-1e555c-f4d8cd-edb183-f15152";
let url = "https://blog.logrocket.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/Creating-animations-p5-js.png";
let palette;
let font;

function preload() {
    font = loadFont("https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1359269/files/Happy Monsters.ttf");
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1112, 834);
    colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100, 100);
    angleMode(DEGREES);
    palette = createPalette(url);
    background(10);
}

function draw() {
    //background(0, 0, 90);

    let offset = 100//width / 100;
    let margin = 0; //offset / 5;
    let cells = 1//int(random(2, 8));
    let d = (width - offset * 2 - margin * (cells - 1)) / cells;
    for (let j = 0; j < cells; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
            let x = offset + i * (d + margin) + d / 2;
            let y = offset + j * (d + margin) + d / 2;
            drawFancyShape(x, y, d, palette.concat());
        }
    }
    frameRate(0.5);
    noLoop();
}

function drawFancyShape(x, y, d, colors, char = String.fromCodePoint(65 + int(random(26)))) {
    let g = createGraphics(d, d);
    let g2 = createGraphics(d, d);
    colors = shuffle(colors);
    let c0 = colors[0];
    colors.splice(0, 1);
    let ratio = 0.2;
    let xStep, yStep;
    for (let y = 0; y < g.height; y += yStep) {
        yStep = random(ratio, 1 - ratio) * g.height / 2;
        if (y + yStep > g.height) yStep = g.height - y;
        if (g.height - y - yStep < g.height / 100) yStep = g.height - y;
        for (let x = 0; x < g.width; x += xStep) {
            xStep = random(ratio, 1 - ratio) * g.width / 2;
            if (x + xStep > g.width) xStep = g.width - x;
            if (g.width - x - xStep < g.width / 100) xStep = g.width - x;
            let r = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                r.push(int(random(5)) * max(xStep, yStep) / 4);
            }
            g.rectMode(CENTER);
            g.fill(random(colors));
            g.noStroke();
            g.rect(x + xStep / 2, y + yStep / 2, xStep - 2, yStep - 2, r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]);
        }
    }
    g2.textSize(g.width * 0.6);
    g2.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    g2.textFont(font)
    g2.textStyle(BOLD);
    g2.fill(c0);
    // g2.stroke(0);
    g2.text(char, g.width / 2, g.height / 2 - g.height / 8);

    let g_tmp = g.get();
    let g2_tmp = g2.get();
    g_tmp.mask(g2_tmp);
    // g_tmp.mask(g2_tmp);
    drawingContext.shadowColor = color(0, 0, 0, 33);
    drawingContext.shadowBlur = d / 10;

    push();
    translate(x, y);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    // image(g, 0, 0);
    let scl = 1.1;
    image(g2, 0, 0, g2.width * scl, g2.height * scl);
    image(g_tmp, 0, 0, g_tmp.width * scl, g_tmp.height * scl);
    pop();

}

function createPalette(_url) {
    let slash_index = _url.lastIndexOf('/');
    let pallate_str = _url.slice(slash_index + 1);
    let arr = pallate_str.split('-');
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = color('#' + arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}

// save jpg
let lapse = 0;    // mouse timer
function mousePressed(){
  // prevents mouse press from registering twice
  if (millis() - lapse > 400){
    save("img_" + month() + '-' + day() + '_' + hour() + '-' + minute() + '-' + second() + ".jpg");
    lapse = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello there! from your code its not obvious what the use of `url` variable is. Also it doesn't point to an image resource so I wonder what you mean by replacing it with a local image. You should describe what you are trying to do with this code.

Comment: its a generative art , and "let url = "https://coolors.co/ffbe0b-fb5607-ff006e-8338ec-3a86ff";"  must be replaced with someting similiar "loadImage"

Comment: That link appears to be broken. I'm not really following what the goal or problem here is. "they not allow the external links" -- does this mean you're getting a CORS error or ...? If so, you could try [cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere). If not, how do you know the external link is disallowed (e.g. specific error message)? Thanks.